# Combining Mesh and FrameLabel in ArrayPlot fails

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would like to create a labeled `ArrayPlot` with `Mesh->True` for example:

```
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, FrameLabel -> x, Mesh->True]
```

This does not show the FrameLabel, but

```
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, FrameLabel -> x]
```

does. I would guess it is a bug, but maybe there is some reason and I can work around it? I am on Mathematica 10.1.0.0 Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `ArrayPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, FrameLabel -> x, Mesh->True]` renders the plot without a frame (hence no framelabel):

```
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, FrameLabel -> x, Mesh->True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What is happening can be seen in a simpler example without `FrameLabel`:

```
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Options[ArrayPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}], Frame]
```

> {Frame -> Automatic}

Somehow adding the option `Mesh->True` sets the option `Frame` to `False`:

```
 ArrayPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, Mesh -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Options[ArrayPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, Mesh -> True], Frame]
```

> {Frame -> False}

The fix is to add the option `Frame->True`:

```
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> x, Mesh -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]